# If statement without condition

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to ask what is the behaviour of the C language on the following:

```
int n = 0;
.
.
// n in this block may change value to something else but a (positive) number
.
.
if(n)
{
  // do something
}
.
.
```

So what the `if(n)` means when the `n` is an integer?

Comment: `if(n)` is equivalent to `if (n != 0)`.

Comment: What do you mean "without condition"? There's blatantly a condition there...

Comment: it evaluates on a true false basis, so if n is 0, its false, else considered true

Comment: It should also be mentioned that unless `n` is of boolean type, this is poor style. Consider `char* str_ptr` with the cases `if(str_ptr)` and `if(*str_ptr)`, easy to slip here and create a bug. Such code is not self-documenting, it is not obvious to the reader if the intent of `if(str_ptr)` was to compare against a NULL pointer or if it is an accidental bug, the programmer meant to compare against nul termination. Instead, it is always better to be explicit. Treat the if statement as if it is a function expecting a boolean parameter. `if(str_ptr != NULL)` and `if(*str_ptr != '\0')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the `C11` standard document, chapter 6.8.4, *Selection statements*,

> `if ( expression ) statement`
>
> A selection statement selects among a set of statements depending on the value of a controlling expression.

and from chapter 6.8.4.1, *The `if` statement*

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.

So, essentially, here, `if(n)` will

- Execute the next statement (block) if `if(n)` results TRUE (`n` unequal to 0, includes both `+ve` and `-ve` values)
- Skip the the next statement (block) if `if(n)` results FALSE (`n` equal to 0)

Comment: Nitpicking: It's not `if(n)` that evaluates but `n`.

Comment: @alk sir, Updated my answer, kindly review.

Answer (score 1):

In C, all integer types that have 0 value, evaluate to false otherwise they evaluate to true. Note that even negative numbers evaluate to true.

In your case if `n` remains 0, the body of the if statement will not execute, because the expression evaluates to false. If `n` gets set to something else than 0, the if statement body will execute.

Answer (score 1):

In the language C, the boolean type is representing with integer so every positive number is considered like the boolean true and only the integer 0 is considered like the boolean false.

Comment: Sry, my previous delete comment was dxxn wrong: It was ment to read "Also negative numbers evaluate to "true". Sry! :-} To cut it short: Everything but `0` is true.

Comment: The boolean type of the C language (`_Bool`) is actually only guaranteed to be large enough to store 1 or 0 (`true` or `false`). Don't mix this up with how if statements work; they behave as they do since the time before C had a boolean type.

Comment: Actually the C Standard defines every non-zero value as `true`, stated in sec. 4.14 of the Standard. Therefore, the phrase "every positive number" is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood what a condition means. A condition need not necessarily contain comparators such as `==` or `<` etc. A condition can be any expression. Now, if the if expression evaluates to a zero value it is considered false and the if statement is not evaluated. Otherwise, it is considered true and the if statement is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bin difficult to understand what you want to ask here, but I'll toss up my 2 cents and you decide if it helps you understand the way `if` statements work.

```
int uiStupidFunction(int num)
{
    return num++;
}

int uiAnotherStupidFunction(int num)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;

    // n in this block may change value to something else but a (positive) number
    //suppose in this way

    n = uiStupidFunction(10);

    if(n)
    {
        printf("n = %d", n);  //prints 10
        //do something
    }
    n = uiAnotherStupidFunction(10);

    if(n)
    {
        printf("n = %d", n);  //prints?
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nHumpty Dumpty sat on a wall");  //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanting to add that if(i) will be the same as if (!!i), checking if it is non-zero.
While, if (!i) is to check for zero.  Since true is 1, and false is 0, !!(true) returns true and !!(false) returns false.  So, it is sometimes useful when the integer is storing perhaps an error code and wanting to normalize its result into a boolean and it is quite short, but I would recommend writing it out to be clear.  (ie; if (i != 0) rather than if (i))

Hope this below helps.

```
    int i1 = -50, i2 = 0, i3 = 50;
    if (i1) 
        printf("if(-50) passed\n");
    if (i2) 
        printf("if(0) passed\n");
    if (i3) 
        printf("if(50) passed\n");
    if (!!i1)
        printf("if(!!-50) passed\n");
    if (!!i2)
        printf("if(!!0) passed\n");
    if (!!i3)
        printf("if(!!50) passed\n");
    if (!!true)
        printf("if(!!true) passed\n");
    if (!!false)
        printf("if(!!false) passed\n");
```

### And then we get the following.

```
OUTPUT:

if(-50) passed
if(50) passed
if(!!-50) passed
if(!!50) passed
if(!!true) passed
```