# While(*x) without another condition

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, strcmp, function-definition

I'm learning about the "strcmp" function , It was concerning to me when looking in the syntax of the function prototype I noticed this "while(*x)" loop  can someone please explain how a while loop works having only one character without any operator (and another char to compare too)  to evaluate if any condition is true or false??
Bellow is the code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

// Function to implement strcmp function
int strcmp(const char *X, const char *Y)
{
while (*X)
{
    // if characters differ, or end of the second string is 
reached
    if (*X != *Y) {
        break;
    }

    // move to the next pair of characters
    X++;
    Y++;
}

// return the ASCII difference after converting `char*` to 
`unsigned char*`
return *(const unsigned char*)X - *(const unsigned char*)Y;
}

 // Implement `strcmp()` function in C
 int main()
 {
char *X = "Techie";
char *Y = "Tech";

int ret = strcmp(X, Y);

if (ret > 0) {
    printf("%s", "X is greater than Y");
}
else if (ret < 0) {
     printf("%s", "X is less than Y");
 }
 else {
    printf("%s", "X is equal to Y");
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You have to show the code you are asking questions about. (Not sure why you're concerned about "no other Boolean expression inside the parentheses." The `while` statement needs only one expression inside the expression. It is in fact quite unusual to see two!)

Comment: Please show the actual code in question instead of a vague description (I for one have no idea what "function prototype" you are talking about)

Comment: "i sew this WHILE(*x)" Please show a complete [mre]. There is likely code you are not showing that is highly relevant to answering your question. For example, an `x++` somewhere.

Comment: @kaylum The OP is asking, how come the seemingly incomplete `while(*x)` works, as opposed to the expected `while(*x == something)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If statement without condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321188/if-statement-without-condition)

Comment: @GSerg yes this answer was very helpful ! i really appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no such keyword as `WHILE`. It seems you mean `while`.

This while statement

```
while(*x)
```

is equivalent to

```
while( *x != 0 )
```

or that is the same

```
while( *x != '\0' )
```

That is the loop continues its iterations until the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string pointed to by the pointer `x` is encountered.

Pay attention to that it is better to rewrite this while loop

```
while (*X)
{
    // if characters differ, or end of the second string is reached
    if (*X != *Y) {
        break;
    }

    // move to the next pair of characters
    X++;
    Y++;
}
```

like

```
while ( *X && *X == *Y )
{
    // move to the next pair of characters
    X++;
    Y++;
}
```

without the redundant if and break statements.

Comment: @0___________ It is a comment. I just copied and pasted the original code as is.

Answer (score 0):

In the C language, any non-zero value is treated as **`true`** and zero as **`false`**.

Because of this, you can use integer values as conditions.

`while(*x)` will execute if the value referenced by `x` is not equal zero.